# Custom Colour Palette on Line Plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I have plotted two columns from a csv file using plt.plot and have achieved the following graph:

[image]

The code for the graph is the following:

```
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=0.50)
```

I have another column within the same csv file that contains the time for each of the x and y values. The time column looks like this:

```
Time,
1000,
2000,
3000,
4000,
5000,
6000,
7000,
etc...
```

I want to impose the time column to act as the color-code for the lines so that they can be coloured according to the time. I have tried this with a scatterplot and it works great...

[image]

...by tweaking the code to this...

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=-x, s=10)
plt.gray()
```

...but I can't get it to work with a normal line plot.

Comment: The easiest solution is the use `seaborn.scatterplot` and set `hue='Time'`. `seaborn` is a high-level api for `matplotlib`.

Comment: Yes I managed to do that, but how do I plot a line graph and do the same?

Comment: with `seaborn.lineplot` and `hue` I would guess. Or plot the scatterplot on the lineplot by calling the two plots sequentially.

Comment: Just tried that, I am getting a blank graph

Comment: Can't do much else to help you since the question doesn't have a complete [mre].

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html